# How do i include precompiled C library in c++

Tags: c++, c, cmake, include

I am fairly new to C++ and i am trying to use a precompiled C library (with .a file format) in my code.

I have a simple CMake project setup and a .a library written in C.
How do i correctly include it and add it to my CMake file?

Comment: What compiler are you using?  GCC?

Comment: Do you have an accompanying header file?

Comment: @Fiddling Bits Yes, GCC

Comment: Have you seen the responses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8774593/3987854), particularly you might try linking to the .a library using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10550334/3987854). Also, please show the code you have tried so far, and what, if any, errors or unexpected behavior you are receiving.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Yes, i do

Comment: You will need a header which declares all the functions from the library.  It will either contain `#ifdef __cplusplus` / `extern "C" {` / `#endif`  / …main contents… / `#ifdef __cplusplus` / `}` / `#endif` or equivalent, or you will include it where needed `extern "C" {` / `#include "header.h"` / `}` so that the functions are known to the C++ compiler to be C functions and not C++ functions.  Add the library (and its directory if necessary) to the linking command line (`-L/where/it/is/lib`, `-lwhatever`).  Add the header directory to the compiling command lines (`-I/where/it/is/include`).

Comment: @squareskittles thank you, the question you linked helped me! i wasnt linking it through cmake correctly